# Two LAN OpenVPN Trouble

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a personal OpenVPN the bulk of whose clients are on two LAN's (the only others are my laptop and phone). How do I connect my computers on one LAN directly by their VPN IP and not their local IP without going through the server on the other LAN?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should set up VPN mesh so that each site has a direct tunnel to other sites. Without site-to-site links, traffic must go through the main site regardless of source/destination.

If you are currently having each machine sign into VPN individually, then you could either offer VPN servers in each site or you can run VPN on the network infrastructure instead (probably less headache).

Comment: Do you know of a guide I can use? Or buzzwords to search for? I'd like to have a VPN server on each LAN.

Comment: If you want to run it on your router, it depends on your what router you are using, and you would need to have something more prosumer/enterprise tier in order to run VPN on the router itself (i.e. Ubiquiti, Juniper, Cisco). If you want to run it on a computer/server, then it depends what software you are using. OpenVPN would be completely manual, see this guide https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/